# Help to identify WW1 or WWII badge

Tags: world-war-two, identification, australia

Can someone identify this badge please.

[image: RSSAILA badge]

It has a number on the back that looks like 742299. What is the significance of the number and why is there a 60 in the crown on the front of the badge.

Answer (score 3):

It's the badge of the Returned Sailor's Soldier's Airmen's Imperial League ([RSSAILA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returned_and_Services_League_of_Australia)).  The number on the back will be the service number, and the '60' on the crown on the front indicates that membership was paid for 1960.

---

A similar badge can be seen (except with a '95', showing that membership had been paid for 1995)  on the [Australian War Memorial site](https://www.awm.gov.au/collection/REL32663/).